# Using lisp for metaprogramming/code generation?

Tags: assembly, lisp, metaprogramming

I am writing an interpreter in almost pure assembler. At the moment I am using a mix of NASM macros and m4 (when those are not powerful enough) to generate large clouds of code.

I remember seeing lisp used as a meta-programming engine for generating and building assembler. I can't recall exactly where though.

Could somebody give examples of projects which use lisp as an assembler meta-programming tool or explain which engines or libraries should be used for this purpose?

Comment: I think I may have confused this for usage of sb-assem:inst which I think is part of SBCL? I can't find documentation on sb-assem...

Comment: The fact this topic was flagged is absolutely stupid. The most informative topics are topics like these. The other week I was reading a thread here about preprocessor recommendations and it was an absolute gold mine, and a month or two before that I found another thread on html/css rendering framework recommendations extremely helpful. By all means continue to enforce the guideline below, but at the loss of everyone.

Comment: your question is off-topic here. Stackoverflow is for programmers with actual programming problems - best with source code and problem descriptions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
*Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.*

Comment: It used to be a pretty idiomatic approach in MuLisp (for MS DOS), it had pretty elaborate inline assembly features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it happens, Paul Khuong has [just written](http://www.pvk.ca/Blog/2014/03/15/sbcl-the-ultimate-assembly-code-breadboard/) about a very similar topic. He uses `sb-assem` to emit code for a simple stack machine.

The machinery is SBCL specific, and you might have trouble figuring out how to use `sb-assem`, but it could be worth a look.

Comment: Any idea where to find documentation for sb-assem?

Comment: I'm not sure whether its documented or not. I couldn't see anything poking around at http://www.sbcl.org/sbcl-internals/, at any rate.